# Drawing text on bitmap in android

Tags: android, image-processing, canvas

I am drawing a text on bitmap in android application and then i am saving it in sd-card.
the image getting saved but there is no text, i mean it seems that there some problem in drawtext, this is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(370, 177, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    c.drawColor(0xffffffff);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(R.color.black);
    //p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    //p.setStrokeWidth(40.0f);
    //p.setTextSize(40.0f);
    //p.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    c.drawText("Some text", 70, 77, p);
    //c.save();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myfile);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bitmap.recycle();
```

am i forget something or what's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R.color.black` is not a real color but just a reference to a color value.
Replace it with `Color.BLACK` or `getResources().getColor(R.color.black)`

```
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

OR

```
p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

Comment: Actually, the color that R.color.black is designating may not be same that Color.Black designates. So the first option is only valid if both colors are the same (which presumably are, but who knows)